# MongoDB PHP Driver Error when doing updateOne

Tags: php, mongodb

I have recently upgraded to PHP7 and to the MongoDB driver from PHP 5.5 and the old Mongo driver. I have changed all the functions from update() to updateOne() and updateMany(), as well as the remove() functions.

However, the first time my application attempts to perform an updateOne error, I am getting an error. The DB connection code looks like this. **Please note that I have added an updateOne function in the constructor as a test once I saw I'm receiving errors :**

```
if (!extension_loaded('mongodb')) die("MongoDB is not installed!");
        try {
            $this->connection = new MongoDB\Client('mongodb://'.$auth.self::HOST.':'.self::PORT.$authDb);
            $this->database = $this->connection->selectDatabase(self::DBNAME);

            # Test function, added due to errors

            $this->connection->WIOC->settings->updateOne(array('_id' => 'xxx'), array('$set' => array('test' => 'yes')));
        } catch (MongoConnectionException $e) {
            throw $e;
        }
```

The error I'm getting is this:

> **Fatal error**:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method
>   MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite::updateOne() in
>   /Users/Idan/Sites/MyApp/include/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Update.php:140
>   Stack trace: 0
>   /Users/Idan/Sites/MyApp/include/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/UpdateOne.php(77):
>   MongoDB\Operation\Update->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server)) 1
>   /Users/Idan/Sites/MyApp/include/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Collection.php(828):
>   MongoDB\Operation\UpdateOne->execute(Object(MongoDB\Driver\Server))
>   2 /Users/Idan/Sites/MyApp/include/mongoConnect.php(30):
>   MongoDB\Collection->updateOne(Array, Array) 3
>   /Users/Idan/Sites/MyApp/include/mongoConnect.php(40):
>   DBConnection->__construct() 4
>   /Users/Idan/Sites/MyApp/include/framework.php(6):
>   DBConnection::instantiate() 5 /Users/Idan/Sites/MyApp/index.php(3):
>   require('/Users/Idan/Sit...') 6 {main}   thrown in
>   **/Users/Idan/Sites/MyApp/include/vendor/mongodb/mongodb/src/Operation/Update.php**
>   on line **140**

var_dump of $this->connection->MyApp->settings shows a MongoDB\Collection, so I assume I'm using the appropriate newer driver.
Even stranger, here is the list of methods for the object:

```
Array
(
    [0] => __construct
    [1] => __debugInfo
    [2] => __toString
    [3] => aggregate
    [4] => bulkWrite
    [5] => count
    [6] => createIndex
    [7] => createIndexes
    [8] => deleteMany
    [9] => deleteOne
    [10] => distinct
    [11] => drop
    [12] => dropIndex
    [13] => dropIndexes
    [14] => find
    [15] => findOne
    [16] => findOneAndDelete
    [17] => findOneAndReplace
    [18] => findOneAndUpdate
    [19] => getCollectionName
    [20] => getDatabaseName
    [21] => getManager
    [22] => getNamespace
    [23] => insertMany
    [24] => insertOne
    [25] => listIndexes
    [26] => replaceOne
    [27] => updateMany
    [28] => updateOne
    [29] => withOptions
)
```

Any idea what is wrong? thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided makes use of [legacy MongoDB driver](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mongo.php) and hence is not compatible with the [new one](http://php.net/manual/en/set.mongodb.php).

Provided you have actually installed the newest driver, the proper way to perform any kind of updates (update/insert/delete) is achieved through the usage of [MongoDB\Driver\Manager::executeBulkWrite](http://php.net/manual/en/mongodb-driver-manager.executebulkwrite.php) method.

The complete sample code is provided below:

```
$manager = new MongoDB\Driver\Manager('mongodb://localhost:27017');
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite;
$bulk->update([ '_id' => 'xxx' ], [ '$set' => [ 'test' => 'yes' ]]);
$manager->executeBulkWrite('DB.Collection', $bulk);
```